# Database appearing in one tool but not another

Tags: mysql, tools

Can anyone think of a reason why a mySQL database would be accessible from one tool (phpMyAdmin, logged in as db_user) but not from another (Sequel Pro, logged in as db_user).

The user is the same in each case and has full rights on the database in question.

In the case that I can't see it, I can access all other databases I would expect to and there are no obvious errors being returned.

The only thing that separates the tools is that phpMyAdmin is running on the same machine as MySQL so uses localhost whereas Sequel Pro uses the domain name.

Comment: Can you connect remote to the server with the domain name via comand line? If this is not working, you might have an network error or are refusing non-localhost connections.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to grant access on a user@hostname basis, not just the user alone. So you will have to grant access to 'sequel_pro'@'your_domain_name' to database_name.*. [Click here for a sample script.](http://stanleyjohns.wordpress.com/2009/11/21/creating-a-user-and-assigning-to-a-db/)